# what does mean by "getting kicked in the head"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, colloquial-language

the context as blow:

> Since my mom taught there, I would no longer have to ride the bus with a bunch of rowdy boys and worry about stuff like getting kicked in the head. No kidding ----they actually accidentally kicked m in the head on day!

if this phrase "getting kicked in the head" can understand by literally, I get it, I thought it as a idiom before. besides, this sentence, "they actually accidentally kicked m in the head on day"! I can't follow it. in my opinion,in a normally condition, how could other people kick the author's head?

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "kick in the head" *can* be idiomatic, for example, ["Ain't that a kick in the head"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xb4P-MZMzJs) by Dean Martin.  The humor in the sentence is that the narrator first gives the impression he's speaking figuratively, and then says no, the meaning is quite literal.

As with many idioms, sometimes you have to figure out from context which is meant.  In this case, however, using it as an idiom makes no sense, so it's not really all that funny.